# Postgres Stored Procedure Transaction and Exception handling

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgres-11

Hi I have more used with SQL procedure. Just trying to achieve below scenarios.

In Postgres Stored Procedure,

1. do we need to commit if there are multiple insert statements
   OR By default Postgressql handle commit and no need to mention (if we don't have anything to handle on Catch OR Rollback) ?
2. How to write , Try/Catch Or Rollback from Stored Procedure ?

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "app"."sproc_data_create"
   ( name varchar(100))
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS
   $$
   DECLARE idIdentity int;
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO data(Name) VALUES (name) RETURNING Id into idIdentity;
    INSERT INTO relationalData(dataId) VALUES (idIdentity);

   // COMMIT , Do we need commit statement  
   // HOW to handle if Rollback or Exception ?
    SELECT idIdentity as Id;   /
    END
   ```

Can someone please guide on this.

Comment: Too many questions in one. Start by reading the PL/pgSQL documentation.

Comment: [Transaction Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) [Trapping Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

Comment: Is "Commit" Required  OR it is by default ? I couldn't find this under documentation but observed, examples without "commit" even though multiple insert statements.

Comment: A function/procedure runs in it's own transaction so there is an implicit commit on completion.

Comment: Ok. Is it still remain when Procedure internally calling "Call <another procedure>"